# Locationlistener mystery

Tags: android, service, locationlistener

I have a service (which extends Service).  In the onCreate event I do the following...

```
    locMgr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locLstnr = new MyLocationListener();
    locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 10, locLstnr);
```

(BTW I have this set for 10 second intervals and it goes off at least every second)

All my information says that if you have a service that extends Service, no matter how many times the activity starts the service it never starts another service and never goes through the onCreate event again (although it does go through onStartCommand again).

I have strong evidence from my logs that I am getting multiple instances of MyLocationListener.  Sometimes 2, sometimes 4, sometimes 8 copies.  If not that, I'm getting multiple copies of my service.

Can anyone see what might be causing this?
Thanks.

Comment: Show us the evidence you are using to make this determination.  Three lines of code is not enough to make a determination about how your application is behaving.  The logs or perhaps the code for the entire `Service`.

Comment: Devunwired: This is not a court of law. My evidence is my logs that indicate that show a pattern that could only be made if multiple copies of my LocationListner were running.  You have to take that as a given.

Comment: A--C: Can you explain to me why other people edit postings?  What did you do to my post and why?  I see it all the time on this forum.

Comment: The fact is there is not enough information here for us to help you.  The logs themselves or some more source code can assist us in figuring out exactly what is going on.

Comment: If you click the link next to where it says "edited" you will get a revisions list of what was changed and any comments the editor added.

Answer (score 0):

It won't go through onCreate again unless it kills the original service.  Which it does fairly often for unknown reasons.  Then it re-creates it.  The cheap way around this is to have your onCreate function start your own service up, so it remains resident.  You'll still lose the contents of memory though.

Comment: Yes, I start the service in the activity onCreate after checking to see if its already running in which case I don't.